# Nesting span Content Tags inside list items in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-tag

How would one go about nesting content tags (spans inside an li) to display the following using the Rails content_tag method:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="something">Groups</a>
     <span>
       <a href="something">Recent</a>
     </span>
     <span>
       <a href="something">Popular</a>
     </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% content_tag :li do %>
  <span>...</span>
<% end %>
```

You can also nest `content_tag`s, but your code may become less readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
content_tag :ul do
  content_tag :li do
    link_to "Groups", something_path
    content_tag :span do
       link_to "Recent", something_path
    end
    content_tag :span do
       link_to "Popular", something_path
    end
  end
end
```

I dont think thats another way to do that using content_tag and i dont think that code is less readable at all. It is just matter of taste. =D

Comment: This seems like it would be correct but the html that is generated is this:<ul>
<li>
<span><a href="some/path">Browse</a></span>
</li>
</ul>